# Modify a page using a button in MediaWiki

Tags: mediawiki

I'm trying to make a to-do list using MediaWiki.  I'm using Semantic MediaWiki with a boolean property "Is Completed" so the jobs that are done don't show up in my to-do list:

I'd like to add a button (or checkbox, or something) on each task page that would modify the page to change the code

```
{{#set:Is Completed=false}}
```

to

```
{{#set:Is Completed=true}}
{{#set:Completed On=<TODAY'S DATE>}}
```

I've tried searching, but haven't found a straightforward way to do this.  Is there any simple way to create a button which, when clicked by the user, runs a custom script that can modify the page?

Eventually I'll add another one to change it back to false, but that should be simple once I've got this part working.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You _could_ probably do that with just a javascript editing the page using the API, but this sounds like something that would be much easier to implement as a parser extension, so I would go straight for that

Comment: Very interesting question. You might also try to get an answer on the SMW mailing lists: https://www.semantic-mediawiki.org/wiki/Semantic_MediaWiki_mailing_lists

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  I'll check out the mailing lists, and look into making an extension.